# prod and sig in COQ

Tags: type-theory, proof-assistants

Hello,

Apparently in COQ the type prod (with one constructor pair) corresponds to cartesian product and the type sig (with one constructor exist) to dependent sum but how is described the fact that the cartesian product is a particular case of dependent sum ? I wonder there is a link between prod and sig but I don't find it explicitely.

Best

Comment: Note that if you don't get any help here (wait a few days), you may want to ask on the Coq mailing list, which you can sign up to without trouble (and post a message here saying you've done so).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the type prod is more akin to sigT than sig. You can use sigT to define a prod' and show there is a bijection between the two types prod and prod' (but they cannot be definitionally equal).

Comment: More precisely, `prodT` and `sigT` (which act on `Type`s) correspond.  I don't know anything `sig`-like that corresponds directly to `prod` (which acts on `Set`s).  One could also define something `prod`-like that corresponds directly to `sig` (which acts on a `Set` and a (dependent) `Prop`).

Comment: But these are pretty much technicalities.  The differences between `Set` and `Type` are rarely relevant (`Prop` is more so).